# Fusion Table in Google Maps will not display entire geometry layer

Tags: google-maps, geometry, google-fusion-tables

I have created a new fusion table in the google drive that contains a large subset geometry placed over certain towns.

However when I go to view the map and the corresponding fusion table overlay, only certain parts of geometry relating to a town will be shown, some towns will not even display an geometry at all.

When viewing this same kml file in google earth all the geometry is displayed correctly.

to demonstrate what I am talking about (view mount barker for a demonstration). 
[Link to google map](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1scR-QveiRdz5PpLqjVxOLvr35Bm9nPQfEMt4FMY#map%3aid=3)

I am also using the map API to search on this fusion table to find locations that located in the geometry regions however when I feed the api a location that is not displayed in the geometry rendering it will return a false result.

There are currently 185 rows in the fusion table. The inital file size of the kml that I imported was about 13mb.

Is there a way to get all the geometry data to show.

Comment: What does the original KML for Mount Barker look like?

Comment: I dont know how I would show you what the original would like unless I  uploading an image of the map with the overlay in google earth.

Comment: You could upload the KML for Mount Barker (not necessarily everything), so I could see what was missing.

Comment: Thats the issue even if I upload just a single town it still will not display the entire geometry set, I believe that @geocodezip was correct with his answer.

Comment: Not to FusionTables. Just the straight KML. If uploaded to a server it should work with KmlLayer and in Google Maps directly, and if worst comes to worst, we can look at it and see what is there.  You could also add the KML for Mount Barker to your question (treat it as "code").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are running into the 10 largest polygons in a multi-geometry display limit:

from [this answer](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/174680)

> Multi-geometry placemarks are supported, but limited to ten polygons during display on a map.

You might need to export each polygon in a separate row.

Comment: Ahhhhh now I understand, thank you very much for pointing me to this resource :)