# Can I group Fusion Table rows into Folders in a Google Earth Network Link?

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-earth

To overcome the limitation with the `<MultiGeometry>` element, I am considering splitting my data into several rows as hinted at in the [Fusion Table Help](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/174680) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638346/fusion-table-in-google-maps-will-not-display-entire-geometry-layer).
This will yield a large amount of rows and I would like to group them into Folders in Google Earth when viewing the Network Link. Is that possible at all ?

Note: there is a similar question left unanswered on the [Fusion Table forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-fusion-tables/dCyZbt1DqzI;context-place=topicsearchin/google-fusion-tables/Folder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, this is not possible.
There is already a related [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=1506) asking for Folder capability (as well as Sub-Folder incidentally). Wait and see, hopefully Google will address this in the near future.